# Count in Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert count stats into a table as one record by using the following code in VBA.  But for some reason, when I go to execute it it says the Number of query values and destination fields are not the same and I am confused as to why this is happening.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
strCount = "INSERT INTO MarketSegmentTotals([State Medicaid], [Commercial], [HIX], [MMP], [CMS Part D (CY " & intYear & ")], [CMS Part D (CY " & (intYear + 1) & ")] ) " & _
"SELECT A.cnt, B.cnt, C.cnt, D.cnt, E.cnt, F.cnt" & _
"FROM ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ImportMetricsIDs " & _
    "WHERE [Market Segment]= 'State Medicaid' " & _
") AS A " & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ImportMetricsIDs " & _
    "WHERE [Market Segment]= 'Commercial' " & _
") as B " & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ImportMetricsIDs " & _
    "WHERE [Market Segment]= 'HIX' " & _
") AS C " & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ImportMetricsIDs " & _
    "WHERE [Market Segment]= 'MMP' " & _
") AS D "

strCount2 = strCount & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ImportMetricsIDs " & _
    "WHERE [Market Segment]= 'CMS Part D (CY ' & (intYear) & ')' " & _
") AS E " & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ImportMetricsIDs " & _
    "WHERE [Market Segment]= 'CMS Part D (CY ' & (intYear + 1) & ')' " & _
") AS F "


db.Execute strCreate
db.Execute strCount2
```

Comment: Is there truly an apostrophe in front of your definition of strCount2?

Comment: No, sorry that was a typo in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a space in your query:

```
"SELECT A.cnt, B.cnt, C.cnt, D.cnt, E.cnt, F.cnt" & _
"FROM ( " & _
```

should be either

```
"SELECT A.cnt, B.cnt, C.cnt, D.cnt, E.cnt, F.cnt " & _
"FROM ( " & _
```

or

```
"SELECT A.cnt, B.cnt, C.cnt, D.cnt, E.cnt, F.cnt" & _
" FROM ( " & _
```

I prefer the first one with the space at the end of the first line as it maintains the line-up of the select and from.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that but now it is saying that there are too few parameters and that it expected one.

Comment: It says it is in the from clause.

Comment: Which one? You have a bunch of from clauses in there.

Comment: It doesn't specify. Would there be a way for me to find out?

Comment: Can you run this query against your datasource directly without involving VBA and have it function correctly? An easy way to do this would be to add a Debug.Print strCount2 in before your db.Execute line, then in your immediate window you can copy the resulting query and run it against your datasource.